# SQL Merge both rows and attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I am new to SQL and am trying to find a simple statement for merging 2 tables (imported from 2 files with different sources), based on unique keys. The merging needs to be both with rows and attributes, effectively merging the two schemas also.

The exact behaviour I'm looking for is:

1. lines with the same key in both tables are merged
2. lines with a key which are not in both tables are included, unchanged
3. attributes with the same attribute name in both tables are merged
4. if the same key has an attribute defined in both tables then table 2 overwrites table 1.

I understand the first 2 can be achieved in a standard FULL OUTER JOIN but you end up with duplicate columns

I also understand that the first 3 can be achieved with a FULL OUTER JOIN plus piping/concatenation, but only if an attribute is populated in one or the other table, not both

I understand that T-SQL has a merge function which but so far I only see it merging rows when there are the same attributes in both.  However, I have not yet chosen the flavour of SQL which will be used.

I'm looking for one of 3 solutions (in order of preference)
1. A way to combine these 4 behaviours into a single standard SQL line
2. A way to combine these 4 behaviours into as few standard SQL queries as possible
3. A way to combine these 4 behaviours which relies on particular features of a SQL variant which is not available in all variants of SQL

Comment: Your question is pretty vague but it seems like you could easily use either aggregates or a case expression to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE` to 'merge' two columns.

```
SELECT 
    -- id's are either the same or non existent in either table
    id   = COALESCE(table2.id, table1.id),
    -- where the join condition is satisfied use table2's values
    -- where the join condition is not satisfied use either table1's or table2's values
    colN = COALESCE(table2.colN, table1.colN),
    -- add columns that aren't in either table
    colX = table2.colX,
    colY = table1.colY
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
```